# drda protocol opening multiple streams

Tags: database

I am trying to connect from my client (Win7-64 bit) to the DB2 server that runs also on a win7-64 bit machine.
I have 3 questions:

1. Does the DRDA protocol supports only SQL databases?
2. When connecting from my client to the server is it possible to connect to a different database at the same time with different streams(connections)?
3. When connecting to a server using the DRDA protocol, is it true that the first Client-To-Server command **MUST** be EXCSAT chained with ACCSEC?

When I searched with Google for this (I could only find information for Q3) I found that the EXCSAT must be the first command in a **DDM** connection, but what about other types of connection? and what this types of connection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Yes; DRDA is only used for communicating with SQL databases.
2. If you're using ODBC or JDBC, you can have separate connections to separate databases with separate handles to identify which database you're talking to.
3. You should be able to find the specification for DRDA at The Open Group web site.  I have 3 tome-sized PDF files (volume 1, the overview, is only 772 pages long; volume 2 FD:OCA is 114 pages; volume 3 DDM is 1168 pages).

The overview indicates (p51) that the client will send an EXCSAT to initiate a connection; it does not mention ACCSEC.

On p123, the diagram shows the EXCSAT message followed by an EXCSATRD from the AR, then the ACCSEC from the client, and an ACCSECRD response.

From this, I conclude that no, the ACCSEC does not have to be chained to an EXCSAT.  I'm not even clear it has to be like that for a DDM connection.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I still however have a problem with Q3. According to the manual in the IBM website([link](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/dzichelp/v2r2/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.ims11.doc.apr%2Fims_ddm_excsat.htm))it says under USAGE that: "During the initial handshaking between the source and target DRDA servers, the source server must issue the EXCSAT command chained to the ACCSEC command." so i am still not sure about this. any idea?

Comment: No; have fun reading the manual, and reporting what you conclude.  On the whole, IBM is more likely to be 'right' in that it actively develops DBMS using DRDA (no-one else uses it, except to connect to IBM DBMS), though the X/Open standard is supposed to be 'the standard'.